# the usual, the Euclidean and the standard topology

Tags: general-topology

What is the difference between the usual, the Euclidean and the standard topology?

Comment: On $\Bbb R^n$, usually the Euclidean topology is standard

Comment: To paraphrase @HagenvonEitzen, they're all the same.  Generated by open balls.

Comment: They are the same only on $\mathbb{R}^n$ ? What about if we are talking about an arbitrary set $X$?

Comment: Explain a little about what you think and where is your doubt

Comment: On an arbitrary set $X$, there is no "usual" topology, and there is no "Euclidean" topology, and there is no "standard" topology.

Comment: Okay, thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $\Bbb R^n$ these terms are **all** used to refer to the topology generated by either the Euclidean metric $d_2(x,y)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}$ or the equivalent metrics $d_1(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - y_i|$ or $d_\infty(x,y)=\max_{1 \le i \le n} |x_i-y_i|$, among others (note these all trivially coincide for $n=1$). It also equals the product topology on $n$ copies of $\Bbb R$ (where $\Bbb R$ has the order topology, which is the same as the metric topology).

It's the topology that's used on $\Bbb R^n$ and its subsets, unless otherwise stated explicitly. It's used in analysis and most applications.

Comment: Okay, now it's clear. Thanks