# $\Bbb R^{n}$ and $\Bbb R^{m}$ are not homeomorphic with respect to what topology when m and n are different?

Tags: general-topology

It is a well known fact that $\Bbb R^m$ is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$ when $n\neq m$. But what is the topology defined on each space? Is it the product topology or any topology? For example if the the topology is $\{\varnothing, \{\Bbb R^n\}\}$ on $\Bbb R^n$ and similarly for $\Bbb R^m$ then any bijection from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: maybe it was specified somewhere but I can't find it.

Comment: It is the product topology, where $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard topology from the metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$.

Comment: oh ok. I kept searching and nobody mentions

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3656560/4280)

Comment: Of course you can give $\mathbb R^k$ many different topologies. However, the commomly accepted practice is to regard it as endowed with its standard topology if nothing else is said. The standard topology is induced by any norm, e.g. by the Euclidean norm. It coincides with the product topology on $\mathbb R^k = \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb R$, where each factor $\mathbb R$ has its "usual" topology.

Answer (score 2):

The spaces $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^n$ are not homeomorphic (when $m\ne n$) with respect to the usual topology, which is the topology induced by the distance$$d\bigl((x_1,\ldots,x_m),(y_1,\ldots,y_m)\bigr)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+\cdots+(x_m-y_m)^2},$$which happens to be equal to the product topology (induced by the usual topology on $\Bbb R$).